# Pivot grid CustomDrawFieldHeader method showing System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException on e.Field property

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, pivot-grid

In my pivot grid, in `pgc_CustomDrawFieldHeader(sender, e)` for certain fields, exception `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than size of collection` is fired in `e.Field` property. This will result to the pivot grid not being rendered. I am looking for some ways to not get the error or at least exit the method if `e.Field` has exception. I need to use `e.Field` and `e.Field.Tag` from `DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotCustomDrawFieldHeaderEventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try moving your code to the **_Init** event

See this page as a reference https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q413762/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-collection